# What is "lay governance" in the context of higher education?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am looking for a basic definition to understand it. I see it used in texts mainly about US higher education systems and governance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*lay* means *non-professional*, as in the word *layman*. So lay governance of higher education refers to governance by people who aren't professional educators.